# How to create materials?

Tags: mesh, materials

I want to know how to use materials, from how to creating them to how to use transparency and colours in them, so please first of all, tell me how to create a new material.I also want to know how (if possible) I can convert faces of an object to a new material.I know this might sound silly but I'm a total beginner and hoping this doesn't waste your time, please help me out here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the material properties in the *Default Layout* on the right side:

[image]

Your object already has a default material you can change the color by changing the settings in the section [*Diffuse*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Properties/Diffuse_Shaders).

To create more materials first create a new slot '+' symbol and press new.

Transparency is setup by ticking [*Transparency*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Properties/Transparency) and ajusting the *Alpha Slider*.

If want to assign materials to single faces select the face and material in *Edit Mode* and press *Assign*.

Since you just started:This is only a tiny part of what you will learn about materials.

Please checkout the resources we already collected here:

[Beginner's Reference](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/beginners-reference)